# Angular radio button in field label

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am using Angular 1.x to submit and process a web form, in particular a radio button:

```
<form name="purchaseForm">
     <div class="radio" ng-repeat="i in cancelTypes.data track by $index">
          <label><input type="radio" ng-model="purchaseAction.cancelReasonId" value="{{i.id}}" />{{i.name}}</label>
     </div>
     <button ng-click="purchaseAction()">Save</button>
</form>
```

In my controller's purchaseAction I can get access to the option id that has been selected with:

```
this.purchaseAction.cancelReasonId
```

However what if I want the name or label of the option rather than the id? The following works but I am not sure if it is the best approach:

```
this.cancelTypes.data[(this.purchaseAction.cancelReasonId-1)].name;
```

Teh other alternative would be to take the id and make a get request to the CancelTypes model but I think this is overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property bounded to the `ng-model` is `purchaseAction.cancelReasonId`. The `value` attribute of the `input` tag is `i.id`. That's why you're getting `id` in the `cancelReasonId`. If you change it to `i.name`, you'll get the name instead. If you want to get the whole object, you'll have to pass just `i` in the interpolation syntax. And then you'll also have to call `JSON.parse` on `purchaseAction.cancelReasonId`

**Give this a try:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.cancelTypes = {
      data: [{
          id: 1,
          name: '1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: '2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: '3'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: '4'
        }
      ]
    };

    $scope.purchaseAction = {
      cancelReasonId: null
    };

    $scope.purchaseActionFn = function() {
      console.log(this.purchaseAction);
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.purchaseAction.cancelReasonId));
    }

  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <form name="purchaseForm">
    <div class="radio" ng-repeat="i in cancelTypes.data track by $index">
      <label>
      <input 
        type="radio" 
        ng-model="purchaseAction.cancelReasonId" 
        value="{{ i }}" />
        {{i.name}}
    </label>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="purchaseActionFn()">
    Save
  </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: so I can only have access to one or the other? I need the id for a save to the db and the name for some the UI

Comment: amazing and very elegant. I was close, but it seems i did not think to set the value of the radio button to be the whole object. Old habits die hard i guess. I knew there was a better way to achieve this goal. I love this solution.